# Fill parts of a shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, fill

Could you please tell me how to fill the highlighted parts of the shape with `fill=gray!60`?

Thank you as always.

[image: desired output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %\draw[thick,latex-latex,yshift=-0.3cm](-138-6:2.5) arc(-138-6:-38+6:2.5) node[midway,left,fill=white]{L};
    %   
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (36.87:4) --+ (-53.13:3) --cycle;
    %\draw[thick] (0,0) --  (-138-5:2.5) arc(-138-5:-38+5:2.5) -- cycle;
    %
    \draw[thick,rotate around={-90-53.13:(3.2,2.4)}](3.2,2.4) rectangle (3.5,2.7);
    %\draw[thick,black,dashed](0,+3.65) --(1.14,+3.65);
    \node[above] at (3.3,2.5) {\large $A$};
    \node[left] at (0.3,-0.26) {\large $B$};
    \node[right] at (4.7,-0.26) {\large $C$};
    %
    %\draw[thick,fill=black] (0,+3.65) circle (0.2mm);
    %
    \draw[thick,rotate around={36.87:(0,0)}] (0,0) arc(180:0:2);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) arc(180:0:2.5);
    \draw[thick,rotate around={-52.73:(3.2,2.4)}] (3.2,2.4) arc(180:0:1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to draw the three arcs first and fill the large one white (or whatever is the current background color).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick, fill=gray!60, rotate around={36.87:(0,0)}] (0,0) arc (180:0:2);
    \draw[thick, fill=gray!60, rotate around={-52.73:(3.2,2.4)}] (3.2,2.4) arc (180:0:1.5);
    \draw[thick, fill=white] (0,0) arc (180:0:2.5);

    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (36.87:4) -- +(-53.13:3) -- cycle;
    \draw[thick, rotate around={-90-53.13:(3.2,2.4)}](3.2,2.4) rectangle (3.5,2.7);

    \node[above] at (3.3,2.5) {\large $A$};
    \node[left] at (0.3,-0.26) {\large $B$};
    \node[right] at (4.7,-0.26) {\large $C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But a much nicer approach would be to draw the three arcs as one single path that can then be easily filled. For this, you just need to apply the calculation directly to the degrees inside the `arc` statement (using this approach you can change the other statements as well to only use multiples of 36.87):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (36.87:4) -- ++({-90+36.87}:3) -- cycle;
    \draw[thick, rotate around={{180+36.87}:(3.2,2.4)}](3.2,2.4) rectangle (3.5,2.7);

    \node[above] at (3.3,2.5) {\large $A$};
    \node[left] at (0.3,-0.26) {\large $B$};
    \node[right] at (4.7,-0.26) {\large $C$};
    
    \draw[thick, fill=gray!60] (0,0) arc ({180+36.87}:{0+36.87}:2) arc
        ({90+36.87}:{-90+36.87}:1.5) arc (0:180:2.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!